# Rails Active Record method to ensure query returns single record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there something in Active Record that ensures that your query does NOT return more than one record?

This is what the basic functionality would be (apologies--this isn't real code but just enough to give the idea of what I'm looking for):

```
Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').single

def single(records)
  if records.length > 1
    raise # or maybe return nil or something like that
  else
    return records.first
  end
end
```

Essentially, this would be a safeguard against accidentally assuming (incorrectly) that your query will always return a single record.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want only one record or specifically the first?

Comment: `.limit(2)` and then check length? But normally I would create unique index in a database.

Comment: If you're trying to do this because your application's business logic states that Only One Of This Thing Should Ever Exist, you're almost-certainly better off enforcing that in the database (with a unique index, or a trigger) rather than checking every time. Better to prevent bad data in the first place than to write code so that if you get bad data, your app doesn't work any more.

Comment: @dax Only one record. Raise when there is more than one record.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Checking length each time I want to do this seems a bit cumbersome. See below for response on other comment.

Comment: @nickgrim I agree. However, extra robustness for free wouldn't hurt, and there are some cases where it might be useful in, say, an rspec (e.g. for conciseness, you don't specify every single attribute but still want to ensure a single record is returned)

Comment: @VictorMoroz great solution! That's exactly what Entity Framework does when you call .Single() in a call chain. How to bring it to ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you can use [`limit`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset)

```
Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').limit(1)
```

Comment: My question is slightly different. I want to ensure that a query returns a single record when I select via the method I've made up 'single'. i.e. for some where, I want to ensure that only one record is a match (whereas a limit will only ensure that I receive one record, whether or not there are multiple matches).

Comment: ah, i see...could you talk a bit more about how you want to use this?  depending on what you're doing, wouldn't it be more straightforward to  just use model validations for uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

you can do Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').single or Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').single or **.limit(1)**

```
Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').first
Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').last
Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find such method in ActiveRecord::FinderMethods.

As alternative solution, you can write it shorter using `tap` method in the case of raising the exception if more than two records exists:

`Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').tap { |r| raise "ERROR" if r.count > 1 }.first`

Considering isolation from other operations, the following code is proper:

`Foo.where(:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq').to_a.tap { |r| raise "ERROR" if r.size > 1 }[0]`

Answer (score -1):

You can also use ActiveRecord find

```
Foo.find_by_thing('this_should_be_uniq')
Foo.find(:first, :conditions => {:thing => 'this_should_be_uniq'})
```

You can also find with multiple attributes

```
Foo.find_by_attr1_and_attr2(attr1_value, attr2_value)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the OP doesn't need to know how to find stuff, they need to know how to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: My first part answers OP's question. find_by/find just returns one record. Exactly what OP is been asking. The second part is some extra information.

Comment: It doesn't; the question isn't "how do I get one thing", it's "how do I raise if there's more than one thing (because the thing should be unique)".

Comment: Yes. But the OP clarified it after i answered this question. Have a look at other answers here.